# Unable to scrape specific site

Tags: import.io

I am unable to use Magic, crawl and build a connector on this site:

http://digitaltmuseum.se

If using "magic" option, import.io just freeze.

If using "crawler", i can create API, but is unable to crawl.

If using "Connetor", after the first recording, the pink button "take me to the next step" never shows up ?

Any thoughts, why this is impossible or any hints on how i could proceed ?

Answer (score 2):

Its impossible because of the javascript used on the site.
Found this solution :http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/623235-infinite-scroll-and-javascript-prerender-beta